# How to filter Core Data managed objects by NSPredicate?

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data

I need to filter the managed objects in the Core Data by NSPredicate. I tried two methods as below to do the filtering task.

- applying NSPredicate during the fetch request process.
- using NSPredicate in the array of all managed objects which provided by the fetch result controller.

Which method is more efficient ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using the NSPredicate on the fetch request would be more memory efficient I would imagine, since those objects are never loaded into memory.

Comment: +1 The predicate in the fetch is vastly i.e. thousands of times, more efficient. For one thing, you don't have to instantiate every managed object to test it the way you must if you do in memory. In theory, you can fetch against an arbitrarily large persistent store while in-memory is limited to immediate app resources.